# Excel Count number of occurances on different worksheets

Tags: excel

I did not find any easy to understand solutions on the forum.
I have four work sheets. Tab1, Tab2, Tab3, Tab4
On each tab (2,3 and 4) cell E3 contains a value.
I want to display the count on Tab1 when the value = 100 for the 3 tabs.
For example, If sheets 3 and 4 have a value of 100, then tab 1's cell should show count as 2.
When tab 2 also has a value of 100, then tab 1 should say 3.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really only have 3 sheets then use this formula

`=(Tab2!E3=100)+(Tab3!E3=100)+(Tab4!E3=100)`

That will count how many of your worksheets have E3 value = 100, if you want to count how many are **at least** 100 change to this:

`=(Tab2!E3>=100)+(Tab3!E3>=100)+(Tab4!E3>=100)`